# Automatically login after registration with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I have an app that allows users to register, login and add content by themselves. 
For authenticated user, they can visit some pages, otherwise it will direct them to login page. However, I could not figure out how to make the user automatically login (go to a page called tools) after the registration. How can I pass the login information from the registration page to the tools page?

Here is my route for tools page and login page:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/tools', {
        templateUrl: 'app/shared/nav.html',
        controller: 'NavCtrl',
        resolve: {
             // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
            "currentAuth": ["$firebaseAuth", function ($firebaseAuth) {
                var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://scurdangular.firebaseio.com/");
                var loginObj = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj);
                return loginObj.$requireAuth();
            }]
        }
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    }); 
}])
```

Here is the registration controller:

```
// Register controller
.controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$location', 'CommonProp', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $location, CommonProp, $firebaseAuth) {
$scope.signUp = function() {

    var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/");
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj);
    var loginObj = $firebaseAuth(firebaseObj);

    var email = $scope.user.username +'@whateverdomain.com';
    var password = $scope.user.password;

    // Sign up implementation 
    if (!$scope.regForm.$invalid) {
        console.log('Valid form submission');

        auth.$createUser({email, password})
               .then(function(userData) {

                    // login user after registration

                    loginObj.$authWithPassword({
                            email: email,
                            password: password
                     });
                     $location.path('/tools');
                     console.log('user creation success', userData.uid);
                            }, function(error) {
                                console.log(error);
                                $scope.regError = true;
                                $scope.regErrorMessage = error.message;
                            });

                    }

            });
        });
    }    
};}])
```

Comment: Some more elegant alternatives can be found in the [routing guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-routes) for Angular/Firebase.

Comment: thank you @Kato, still learning, will make it look better in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like `$createUser()`, [`$authWithPassword()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-authwithpasswordcredentials-options) returns a promise. That promise is fulfilled when the user has been authenticated, which is the time you want to redirect them:

```
 loginObj.$authWithPassword({
     email: email,
     password: password
 }).then(function(authData) {
     $location.path('/tools');
 });
```

Comment: Example of this in [AngularFire-Seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed)